# How do I remove outer/container divs from a view?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view which uses "unformatted list" as it's output format.

```
<div class="view view-featured-causes-view view-id-featured_causes_view view-display-id-block view-dom-id-961c974a51410cb04cdd2a2be4f3c589">
<div class="view-content">...</div></div>
```

Now I want these divs to be stripped.

I tried the solution in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25541/remove-divs-and-spans-from-view-output), but I just want to change the format. I do not want to use [Semantic views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews) as that does not help at all in my case.

I manually created a views theme (copying unformatted list) and changing its code as:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
    </div></div><?php print $row; ?><div><div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but that deeply craps out my overall design.

What is the most appropriate and simplest way to do this?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan : I don't this this is a duplicate, if I read the OP correctly. The other question talks about rows wrapper elements, this one about the outer/view wrapper divs.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan as I mentioned in the question, that answer did not solved my problem.

Comment: of course, I did. please read my question. I mentioned that in there already :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the views-view.tpl.php, not the views-view-unformatted.tpl.php.

The two divs you mention are originating from [sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view.tpl.php/7.x-3.x), check out lines 30 and 55.

If you copy this over to your theme's templates folder, and rename to be specific to your page/block display, you can remove that part of the template's code and you should get what you need.

> cp sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view.tpl.php 
>   sites/all/themes/your_theme/templates/views/views-view--your-ul-page.tpl.php

N.B.: This is exactly what the [other post's accepted answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/25618/57183) is doing in the first part, before going into Semantic Views configuration, you can ignore that part. Here is a modified/simpler version of the code snippet from that answer, for quick reference:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">     // 30: delete this line
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
[...]
<?php if ($rows): ?>
    <div class="view-content">  // 55: delete this line, 
      <?php print $rows; ?>
    </div>                      // 57: delete this line
  <?php elseif ($empty): ?>
[...]
</div><?php /* class view */ ?> // 90: delete the div from this line
```

Good luck!

Comment: sure thing, I really think this is not a duplicate btw. Good thing you mentioning the other answer in your OP. Cheers!